# Where did this extra space come from?

Tags: html, css

[image: There's a very small line of space under the ADVANCED SEARCH]

The code:

HTML:

```
<div id = "LeftDiv">
    <p class = "hdr">ADVANCED SEARCH:</p>
    <div class = "LeftItem">
        <form>
            <p style="margin:0;padding: 10px 0;">Weird Space above this</p>
            <input type = "text" name = "search" />
            <input type = "submit" value = "Go" />  
        </form>
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    ...There are some more (like a vertical navigation bar,
    which also has this gap between the header and the navigation bar)
```

CSS:

```
#LeftDiv
{
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

.LeftItem
{
    background: #000 url("") no-repeat;
}

.hdr
{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: url("header.png") no-repeat;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The weird thing is, this happens in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Also, this space disappears when I zoom when using Firefox.

I'm not really sure why this happened. Is this because the `<p>` is not inside the 'LeftItem' div?

Comment: What happens if you make the hdr p a div?

Comment: Why you just don't simply remove the p tag and see what happens

Comment: same thing, I just added the p tag for you guys to see clearly that gap...

Comment: @Robot Woods, do you mean to insert the p  into another div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding no margin/padding for every element:

```
*
{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

**EDIT REGARDING YOUR COMMENTS**:
You don't want to use padding to fit your image in. What you do is get your image width and height, and do this:

```
.hdr
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display:block;
background:url("header.png") no-repeat;
}
.hdr span
{
font-weight:bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 6px auto;
}
```

(instead of 100px, use actual size, and 6px is a wide guess)
ANd then use html:

```
<div class="hdr"><span>advanced search</span></div>
```

Comment: Done that except the padding in the .hdr class. I needed the padding: 10px 0; in the .hdr class.

Comment: then try removing the padding for bottom: `.hdr{padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;}`

Comment: the gap is gone, but so does the lower part of the "ADVANCED SEARCH" header. I need 10px for both the top and bottom, and 20px for the font = 40px height of the "ADVANCED SEARCH" image.

Comment: Use this then: `padding: 10px 10px 9px 10px;` I'm guessing the bottom padding goes 1px too far.

Comment: How weird, I've done that before you commented :) The space is gone on normal zoom level (I don't know how to call it). But it's still there whenever I zoom out too much. Also with this, the background image is now cut when using Chrome.

Comment: Cool! That solved it! One last problem though the "ADVANCED SEARCH" is now written at the upper part of the image, since the 10px of padding before is now gone. Also, what is the 6px padding of the span for?